# Tracking changed files with git without saving changes

Tags: git

My file layout is like so

```
~/foo/
foo.pl
Foo.pm
    ~/foo/data
        ~/foo/data/an_article.txt
        ~/foo/data/an_article/
            ~/foo/data/an_article/image.jpg
            ~/foo/data/an_article/movie.mp4
        ~/foo/data/another_article.txt
        ~/foo/data/another_article/
            ~/foo/data/another_article/audio.mp3
            ~/foo/data/another_article/raster.nc
```

Of course, I want `git` to track the changes to all the text files (the programs, CSS, html templates, and the articles with extension **.txt**). With regards to the binary files, I want `git` to track **only** their latest version. So, if I change **movie.mp4**, `git` *should* include the latest version in its `push` and `pull`, but `git` should *not* save the previous version. In other words, I want `git` to do its thing on everything except the binary files, but for binary files `git` should pretend like it is `rsync`.

#### Logic

As is evident from the layout above, `~/foo/data` is really my data store. Every article has its own, identically named folder with any relevant binary files. This ensures all related files are in close proximity. If I move the binary files outside this structure then not only do I have to concoct a separate deployment script (perhaps an `rsync` that synchronizes the binary files), more importantly, I destroy the logical structure of my data store.

Suggestions?

Comment: > Suggestions?
Store your binary files outside of git. While technically doable, the behavior you want would contradict the nature of git.

Comment: yes, what I am trying to achieve would go against the grain of `git`. However, I have added more info to the question above under the section titled **Logic** to explain why I want this, which might help figure an efficient and effective solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As is evident from the layout above, ~/foo/data is really my data
>   store.

for a data store based on git, see git annex: http://git-annex.branchable.com/

for erasing history from git: *no such thing*, see Bruno Reis' explanation above.

Comment: didn't know about `git-annex`. Thanks. Reading through its docs, I saw a mention of `git-media` and reading up on that, it seems I probably need `git-media` more than `git-annex`

Answer (score 8):

Git doesn't work the way you want. A new commit depends on older commits: when calculating the SHA-1 of the new commit, the SHA-1 of the parent commits is included in the calculation. This is exactly what makes Git *secure*: any modifications to older commits can be detected and would destroy the history.

Answer (score 1):

Pull in the binary files as part of a deploy script.